# After running `ssh-add -K` to add my SSH key to the Apple Keychain, what is the name and type of entry shown in Keychain Access.app?

Tags: macos, terminal, password, keychain, ssh

Supposedly this console command will add my private SSH key to the [Apple Keychain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keychain_(software)), as discussed in [*this Answer*](https://superuser.com/a/1163862/212610) on the Question, [*How to use Mac OS X Keychain with SSH keys?*](https://superuser.com/q/88470/212610):

```bash
ssh-add -K path-to-my-private-key-for-SSH
```

If that succeeds…

➥ What is the type and name of the entry to be found in the [*Keychain Access.app*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keychain_(software)#Keychain_Access)?

I would like to be able to manually verify and possibly delete that entry.

Answer (score 5):

If you key is not passphrase protected, it looks like macOS won't add it to the Keychain. Presumably this is because the only thing the keychain stores is the passphrase. Everything else seems to require messing with the `~/.ssh/config` file.

**If your ssh key is passphrase protected, running `ssh-add -K path/to/key` adds your passphrase to your keychain as a generic password prepended with "SSH:".** Also, as for remembering keys, starting with macOS Sierra, Apple chose to stop remembering keys by default. See a brief article (with some external sources) about debugging some SSH problems: https://medium.com/@medley56_82999/i-recently-went-down-a-rabbit-hole-debugging-some-ssh-problems-cross-platform-and-wanted-to-make-bc6890eaf758

Answer (score 3):

It's a little fiddly, but this works on even the latest version of Mojave (as of Darwin 18.2.0)

**Prior to Mac OS 10.12.2 (Sierra is 10.12):**

Edit ~/.ssh/config:

```
    Host *
    AddKeysToAgent yes
```

**Mac OS 10.12.2 or greater:**

Edit ~/.ssh/config:

```
    Host *
    UseKeychain yes
    AddKeysToAgent yes
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/<private key filename>
```

Comment: Yes, [`UseKeychain` is required since 10.12.2](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2449/_index.html) for `ssh` to automatically use the stored ssh key. `AddKeysToAgent` is optional though, only if you want it to automatically add all keys you use to the Keychain.

Comment: If you only want to use SSH agent, and not store passwords in Keychain, you can omit the `UseKeychain` option.

Answer (score 1):

Open the keychain app, click on the category "passwords", click add, and put the path to the SSH file as the account name:

[image]

Now, `ssh-add -A` should automatically add the key to your ssh-agent without any further hassle.

Answer (score 0):

In Keychain, just do a search for "ssh".

Or you can find it under:

Keychain: `Local Items`
Category: `Passwords`
Name: `SSH: /Users/xxxxx/.ssh/id_rsa`

You will most likely need to quit and restart Keychain to refresh the list. It helps to sort by Date Modified. You can also try `View > Show invisible items`.

**Additional note:**

`ssh-add -K` will add the key to the Keychain. However, `ssh-add -D` will not delete the key from the Keychain (it only deletes from `ssh-agent`/`ssh-add -l`). So you are right that is good to check the Keychain.